# Converse phrase for "in writing"

Tags: expressions, idioms, idiom-requests

Is there an converse phrase to "in writing", in the sense of completing a task or a calculation in-writing? This should have the sense of "in explicit thought, but not in physical writing".

PS - Not sure whether this is a phrase-request or an idiom-request, please retag as appropriate.

Comment: It would really depend on the context. A committee has hashed out a policy after several meetings?  A student has come up with a solution to a math problem or a transportation engineer has come up with a traffic congestion solution?  Your "task" is too broad.  **formulated** is a possibility. As is **devised**. They don't imply that it is in writing but neither do they imply that it is not in writing.

Comment: **developed** is another possibility. A colloquial phrase would be ***come up with* [a solution]** or even **to have a solution *in mind***  but that suggests not yet fully perfected or completed or fully put to the test.

Comment: I advise giving a sentence to demonstrate the context of this phrase/word.

Comment: Your question confuses me - I've only ever heard the phrase "in writing" refer to formalizing some agreement or contract or promise, used in opposition to verbal or otherwise informal agreements/contracts/promises. I suggest that if you're providing an alternate definition to "in writing" and you want an opposite, you should first provide a valid source for this alternate definition.

Answer (score 5):

The converse for the sense of "in writing" used in the examples on the page linked in the question is "orally" or sometimes "verbally."  This has to do with a written commitment or a written agreement, which is seen as firmer or more serious because it involves physical evidence of the terms of the commitment or agreement rather than relying on people's memory.

The sense you're asking about, however, is typically opposed to "in one's head."  For example, I would need to work out the product of 589 and 62843 in writing, but I can figure the product of 13 and 14 in my head.

(That said, I'd probably say "on paper" before I'd say "in writing," but then again these days I'd more likely use a calculator than any form of writing, whether it be on paper or otherwise.)

Comment: I wouldn't mention "orally" or "verbally" as the converse. +1 if you drop it :-)

Comment: @einsupportsModeratorStrike I wouldn't have mentioned it either but for the link in the question.  I'd consider dropping it if the link were removed from the question.  (Furthermore, I notice that the definition given for the phrase there doesn't encompass the sense being asked about terribly well.)

Comment: Dropped the link.

Comment: Oh, yes, I did it *in my head*, or *learned it by heart*.

Comment: In most contexts in which one encounters *in writing*, it is used in contrast to *oral* or *verbal*. The question makes it clear that these are not the contexts that the OP is interested in, but it is still worthwhile for an answer to note that, as the answers on this site are meant to help everybody who may come to this page in the future, not just the OP. Many people will come to this page on the basis of its title, and *oral/verbal* would be the best answers to what appears in the title, even though they are indeed not answers to the question that the OP presented.

Answer (score 2):

Though I'd opt for 'in one's / your / my ... head' as phoog says, one sense of **mentally** must correspond to this sense of the related adjective **mental**:

> *mental*  ...
>
> 3. [adjective] [prenominal]: A mental act is one that involves only thinking and not physical action ['physical action' considered to include, for instance, the writing down of working in arithmetical calculations].
>
> - *Practise mental arithmetic when you go out shopping.*
> - *Graham made a quick mental calculation.*
> - *She made a mental note not to sit anywhere near him.*

[[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mental)][augmented]

This is more formal than 'in my head', and the adjectival usage in this sense is more common than the adverbial, usually with collocating nouns as in the examples Collins gives. But 'He worked out the square root of 1296 mentally' has context allowing the desired sense.

Comment: *Mentally* may indeed work in some contexts, but in others it won't be obvious that it is used in the sense of '**only** thinking and **not** physical action', rather than in a sense that allows for mental operations to be combined with using pen and paper. (The OP hasn't made it clear in what contexts the word is to be used. ) *In one's head*, informal as it is, is unambiguous in that respect: it always rules out the use of pen and paper (as well as computers and suchlike).

Answer (score 0):

> ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/verbally)) **verbally**
> in a way that is spoken rather than written:
> • The judge then verbally agreed to the attorney's request.
> • I have repeatedly asked parents, both verbally and in writing, not to park here.

Comment: If you've done something alone - which you may have in my scenari - you haven't done it verbally; so this isn't the right phrase.

Comment: @einsupportsModeratorStrike True, this is only a particular case, and perhaps not the most frequent, although nowadays all sorts of plain problems are resolved through mere discussion among team members.

Answer (score 0):

The converse would be **in contemplation**. According to [Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20contemplation) it means:

> being thought about or considered

They give a number of real life example excerpts, one of which certainly sketches a situation in which no writing is involved:

> In a film that flirts between reality and fantasy, Bisschop’s favorite scene is when Stanley, on the way to the moon, is upside down in his spacecraft and stares *in contemplation* at the void beyond, a streak of sunlight across his face.
>
> —Wilson Chapman, Variety, 5 Apr. 2022

Comment: Can you give an example of "in contemplation" being used in the context I described?

Comment: @einpoklum I guess not. With the 'in writing' idiom the emphasis is mostly on whatever it is that is in writing while with this idiom the emphasis seems to be more on the act of contemplating. If the focus is about thinking about something specific then Edwin Ashworth's answer is probably more suitable.